# Can you set keyboard shortcuts for status menu applications, without using Automator?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts-app

I'm using a free 3rd party annotation app, called IPEVO Annotator.  It is an application installed in the Applications folder, but it does not actually have an active application icon as would normally appear in the application switcher.  Instead, it launches a Status Menu icon.  There is an option for displaying/hiding the controls for the program, but unfortunately there is no keyboard shortcut for it.

I would like to create a keyboard shortcut that toggles this menu item on/off, but can't seem to find an easy way to do it.  I really don't want to have to mess with Automator and creating a service if at all possible.  The built-in macOS keyboard shortcuts are not able to select from Status Menu applications.

Is there any other way to assign a keyboard shortcut to such application menus?

Comment: does the app has a menu bar ?

Comment: Just its icon in the Status Menu.  It has no title or name, just the icon.

Comment: anything that has a menu bar with commands can be made in to Keyboard shortcuts. Without the menu bar, you could use Automator to create shortcut.

Comment: OK, then how can I make a shortcut for a menu bar that has no name or title?  From my reading I would need to use Automator to create a service so that the keybinding can be picked up and activated as needed.  I really don't want to have a whole additional service running at all times just for this if I can help it.  Is there some other way?

Comment: you would use Automator service and `watch me do`.

Comment: Which is exactly what I don’t want to do, and is exactly why I explicitly created this question to find an alternative solution.

Comment: than I can not help you further. Good luck. PS and for your information, Automator is highly integrated service and will not slow down your system and the keyboard shortcuts do not run all the time, only when the specific applications is called for.